# How to specify -log parameter in cleartool update command

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I am trying to automate updating my clearcase view and build the code in a bat file. I want to run the update command and then check the log to verify its success. For this I want to save the update log in a specified location rather than its default location

Now, cleartool allows you to specify your own log file within the cleartool console

cleartool>update -log pname

but when i use the same as a single command, it doesnt work

D:> cleartool -log pname  --------- THIS DOESNT WORK

any ideas?

Thanks
RB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do (from [`cleartool update` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm)):

```
 cleartool update -log pname /path/to/root/view/directory
```

A `cleartool update` outside a view won't work.
A `cleartool update` with the path of a root view directory will work.

If you specify that root directory, then you can execute the `cleartool update` command from any path, including `D:\`.

```
pname ...
```

> If you do not specify `–add_loadrules`, this argument specifies the files and directories to update.
>   **All specified directories, including the root directory of the snapshot view, are updated recursively**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its working now. I read through the same man page all of yesterday but was foolishly trying cleartool -log pname update <view>.

Comment: @RusticBit I have to say, their "`-log pname pname`" syntax isn't exactly clear...